# DB error in 'civicrm_group_roles' module

Tags: drupal, database, modules, plugin, bug-reporting

When I log in to my site and I have the `civicrm_group_roles` module enabled, I'm getting this generic error in the browser:

```
Error
The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.
```

In the database log, I see this error message:

```
PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table
'singersin_drupal.singersin_combined.civicrm_group_roles_rules' doesn't exist:
SELECT r.name AS name, cgr.role_id AS role_id, cgr.group_id AS group_id FROM 
{civicrm_group_roles_rules} cgr INNER JOIN {role} r ON r.rid=cgr.role_id; Array ( ) in 
civicrm_group_roles_sync_roles() (line 821 of 
/Users/ken/src/SIA/server275-site/sites/all/modules/civicrm/drupal/modules/civicrm_group_roles/civicrm_group_roles.module).
```

Note the table name `singersin_drupal.singersin_combined.civicrm_group_roles_rules` - that's actually the **Drupal** database name, followed by the **CiviCRM** database name, followed by the table it's looking for.  So I assume that somehow the `{civicrm_group_roles_rules}` token is getting filled in wrong when the site has different databases for Drupal and CiviCRM.

I can work around this by disabling the `civicrm_group_roles` module (`drush dis civicrm_group_roles`).

I'm using:

- CiviCRM 5.32.2
- Drupal 7.76

Comment: Just noticed I didn't *exactly* ask a question.  The question is: how can I fix this, and/or should I open a bug in the CiviCRM tracker somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Drupal 7.76 was only current for about a day, because of this bug (which affects other integrations, but hits CiviCRM especially hard). Upgrade to Drupal 7.77.

Comment: Thanks, I must have had particularly bad timing.  Will do.  I saw things about "table name quoting for MySQL 8" in the release notes for 7.77, but figured it didn't apply since I'm using mysql 5.7.x.